# Background_position not working

Tags: html, css

I can't get background-position to work.  I've tried putting the code everywhere I can think of!!!  Any ideas???  Thanks

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogPrxV

My html is

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

My css is

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: red;
    background-position: center;
    text-align: center;
}

.inner {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 160px;
    width: 320px;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background: green url("welcome-small.png") no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: By the way, which `background-position` can't you get working? the `.container` or the `.inner` or both? You wish to have the `.container` be in the center?

Answer (score 1):

You're using shorthand for the background image so you should include the position within the background: style.

```
.inner {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 160px;
    width: 320px;
    background: url("welcome-small.png") no-repeat 50% 50% green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `margin` to center your `container` and remove the extra `background` property you have.

```
.container {
    width: 80%;
    background-color: red;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is your updated codepen that shows it centered.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwVXGv

Answer (score 1):

your `background` property rewrites the background-position,  see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/pd11wquz/)
This is because background will also set the background-position to `0 0` by default.

```
.inner {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 160px;
    width: 320px;

    background: green url("http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-position: 20% 50%;
}
```

just take the `background-position` property below `background` property

---

Also if you want the inner to be horizontally in the center use margin-auto: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/pd11wquz/1/)

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  background-position: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.inner {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 160px;
  width: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  background: green url("http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg") no-repeat;
  background-position: 20% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `background` property is shorthand for **all** background properties. It  **overides** any previously stated *individual*  properties already set.

Perhaps the simplest solution here is just to move the background position setting to **after** the shorthand

```
.inner {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 160px;
    width: 320px;
    background: green url("welcome-small.png") no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.inner {
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 160px;
    width: 320px;
    background: green url("welcome-small.png") no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry- I didn't see your answers - the site didn't email me when I got a response so I didn't realise (I got an answer elsewhere)!!!

Basically - what I needed was margin: auto (because I have a div nested within a div).  It is easy when you know how!!!  ;-)

Thanks for your help guys.  Dayan was right on the money!!!